# Legendary average IVs

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Pokemon X and Y, I checked my Yveltal and it has 3 perfect IVs. A friend of mine told me that having 3 IVs on average in Pokemon X/Y for Yvetal and Xerneas is normal. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm trying to narrow down the exact generation where this became a mechanic, but at least as of Generation VI, all Pokemon encountered in the wild that are unable to breed (Legendaries, baby Pokemon, etc.) are guaranteed 3 "perfect" (31) IVs.

Comment: None of my legendaries from Gen V (both B/B2) have three 31s, so that seems to narrow it down quite well.